# multiple year comparison chart

Tags: charts, powerbi, comparison, powerbi-desktop

I am looking to create a chart in Power BI to compare weekly data from previous years to levels this year, similar to the screenshot below from excel.

5-years of historical data in the shade with this year as a line chart.

[image: Screenshot of Excel chart]

Have tried to use similar method to excel

- take min and max figures from the weekly data
- get the difference between the two values
- in charting: take the min value and use stacked area to shade range above with the difference between the min & max
- place this years data as a line chart